# Printing a Jtable as Table into file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I was in the process of creating an application for Finance Management.So I am trying to get the final job getting the summary printed.
Ths summary page consists of different tables and each followed by two labels and text field.
So it would be great if someone can help me with some light into this.

All I want is print a populated Jtable onto file as it is.

I am not an expert with Java and Im using Netbeans for coding the gui.

Also regarding the fileformat i think it has to .rtf for supporting lines etc.Hope there wont be difficulty in creating rtf file from this.

Ps: Im not really particular with format .rtf I just want a format which can support Columns and Tables.

One more thing I wanted to add is that I want to create receipts from custom templates.I was thinking of using .rtf files as templates and adding neccessary values to the file. But after editing the file in java, it doesnt seem to be looking fine. It would be better if someone could suggest me a suitable format

Edit:

Ive managed to get a readymade code for printing jtable to pdf and it's working well and good. Code is as follows

`Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    try {
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\Users\arun\Desktop\jTable.pdf"));`

```
  document.open();

  PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

  cb.saveState();
  Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphicsShapes(500, 500);

  Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
  g2.clipRect(0,0, 500, 500);

  table.print(g2);
  g2.setClip(oldClip);

  g2.dispose();
  cb.restoreState();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"done","done",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
document.close();
```

But the table is being printed close to the left side of page.I wanted to leave a left margin and also heading of each table column is to be printed.

I tried document.setmargins() .But it is not working. Regarding the headings of column, I have not clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out the data by retrieving the `TableModel` from the JTable via `jTable.getModel()`, iterate over the contents using `model.getRowCount()`, `model.getColumnCount()` and `model.getValueAt(row, col)`, and finally print the values to an ordinary `FileWriter` if you don't want any 3rd party tools.

See [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29), [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), [FileWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), [BufferedWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) in the API docs.

Comment: Isnt it possible to write Table into files without using any third party tools. I just want to keep it simple and I have no real affinity towards any particular format.

Comment: Sure, you can just use standard java.io to dump the contents of the JTable model to a file. Could provide a snippet later if necessary.

Comment: Please give a snippet if it's possible. Please make sure that the the table is printed as table itself into the file and just the values printed.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.Ive managed to get a considerably working code

Answer (score 1):

1. A third party tool like iText will be helpful in creating rtf files.  Especially if you want to create tables.
2. I would suggesting writing the data from the classes that contain your model rather than trying to pull it out of the GUI (JTable).
3. I highly recommend against using a GUI Builder to generate applications when you are not already familiar with Swing. (Even then I recommend against it, just not as strongly).

Comment: I am not really particular with the format rtf. I just want to be able to add columns to the file.

Comment: Regarding pulling out the data, Jtable is populated using a database query.So i dont think your option will work

Comment: Instead of populating the table directly from the database you should separate the model and view some.  Also, you question is unclear do you want to write the file in rtf format or not?

Comment: I am not particluar about using rtf format. Ijust want the table to be printed as it is into the file ( i mean just as table itself). Any suitable format for the pupose will do ,better if we keep the procedure simpler

Comment: @Hello, in that case part 1 becomes simpler, just writing the data out to a text file through a FileWriter or something similar.

Comment: Dude, you are missing my point!!! I want it to be written as tables with rows and columns!! How can we write a table in a .txt file?

Comment: Files have a format, whether it is rtf, txt, xml, a serialized object, you are just going to have bytes in that file.  "Rows and Columns" is not specific enough, what format/structure/etc. does the file need to be in?

Comment: @jzd thanks.Ive fixed to put it into pdf format. And Ive added the code in Edit